# preserve generate_series rows through joins

Tags: postgresql

I have a histogram query that filters the entities counted by conditions that can only be checked if joins are used.

The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT gs.t, COUNT(packets.id) FROM packets
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT generate_series(NOW() - '72 hours'::interval, NOW(), '1 hour') AS t) gs
ON packets.transceived_at > gs.t AND packets.transceived_at <= gs.t + '1 hour'
JOIN devices ON devices.id = packets.device_id
WHERE devices.mandate_id = 3
GROUP BY gs.t;
```

Sadly this will omit rows where there's no packet that was received between gs.t and gs.t + '1 hour'.

This does not happen when I don't join devices, but I need that table (and others in derivative queries) to filter some devices.

Is there a way to still get all rows of `generate_series` even when using joins?

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN devices ON devices.id = packets.device_id
AND devices.mandate_id = 3;` But the real question: what do you want to count? Do you want to count packets? Or devices? Or packets that have a specific device?

Comment: And that `SELECT gs.t` without a `GROUP BY` looks suspicious. Please provide the whole query.

Comment: I added the group by clause, I originally deleted it because it contained another column that was not important for this question.
As for your other question, I want to count packets, that's why I have packets.id in the count function.

Comment: Rather than giving people a query that doesn't do what you want, you should give them sample data and a desired output.

Comment: The idea with the condition in the on-clause works well btw.

Comment: Sorry I kept this so vague, I have 2 other queries that are similar and on top of all this the queries are built with a query builder with a common core query (the part with generate_series, select, group by). The difference in all these are the joined tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the COUNT of each element of the series you can use an scalar subquery.

```
WITH gs AS
(
    SELECT generate_series(NOW() - '72 hours'::interval, NOW(), '1 hour') AS t
)
SELECT gs.t, (SELECT COUNT(packets.id) 
              FROM   packets 
              JOIN   devices 
              ON     devices.id = packets.device_id
              WHERE  devices.mandate_id = 3
              AND    packets.transceived_at > gs.t 
              AND    packets.transceived_at <= gs.t + '1 hour')
FROM   gs;
```